# Configuring gitlab ci for Android project

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a '.gitlab-ci.yml' file in my project root:

```
job_build_debug_apk:
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease
  stage: deploy
tags:
  - android
allow_failure: true
```

while I push to the master, it will build and is succesed, but I can find any apk file in my project.

This is my log:

```
running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.4.2 (bcc1794)
Using Shell executor...
Running on userMacBook-Pro.local...
Fetching changes...
Removing .gradle/
Removing app/build/
Removing build/
HEAD is now at 3ae32fc back back
From http://gitlab.xxx.com/naiyu/AdminYDT
   3ae32fc..5312eaa  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 5312eaaf as master...
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
:app:compileReleaseShaders
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:prePackageMarkerForRelease
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
:app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:app:packageRelease
:app:assembleRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 32.012 secs
Build succeeded
```

My runner executor is `Shell` on my Mac OS.

Is there any wrong with my path, or is there has any blog to show this.

Comment: This post, written by an Android developer of Snapchat, might help you: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/

He explains how to build and test an Android app with GitLab CI, gives the code you need for `.gitlab-ci.yml` and break it into parts, explained one by one.

Comment: @martijn-pieters I was just trying to help, and you haven't given me time to edit my answer. This is so unfair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gitlab CI works like that: you `push` changes to the server and your local runner make a `clone` (or a `pull`) of your latest changes.

The sources will be downloaded in a subfolder of the runner, not in your project. This means that the apk will be in one of these subfolders as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have found the apk as you said. Now I have change the default build path.